# How can a run a 'Dev' instance and have Mist running on Geth at the same time?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I have Mist open and running on the Geth Node but want to run a local dev environment using `geth --datadir ./.ethereum/devnet --dev console`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run geth **first** in your private chain (dev mode)

```
geth --datadir ./.ethereum/devnet --dev console.
```

**then** run Mist it will automatically connect to the running geth.  .